# Do While Loop - Undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

Good day guys, I want to ask why my variable was undeclared although i declared it at first.
my typeSel variable in the while loop does have an underline which was found undeclared identifier.
Thanks for helping

```
int quantity, typeSel; // quantity, modify type
double weight;
string w,q; // weight, quantity
char modSel; // modify selection


if( modSel =='y'|| modSel == 'Y'){

    do{
        cout << "What do you want to change : " << endl;
        cout << "1. Flavour" << endl << "2. Weight" << endl << "3. Quantity" << endl;
        cin >> typeSel;
    }while(typSel != 1 && typSel != 1 && typSel != 1);

    if(typeSel == 1){
        Flavour();
    }
    else if(typeSel == 2){

    }
    else if(typeSel == 3){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`typSel` and `typeSel` are *not* the same identifier.

Let's have a look at them in close proximity, maybe it will be clearer:

```
typSel
typeSel
   ^
   |
   +-- here
```

:-)

In addition, while I appreciate some people may not totally trust computers, asking then to verify a variable isn't a specific value shouldn't need to be done *three* times. You may want to check for a couple of other values than just `1`.

Change:

```
}while(typSel != 1 && typSel != 1 && typSel != 1);
```

into:

```
} while (typeSel != 1 && typeSel != 2 && typeSel != 3);
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's a typo: `typSel` != `typeSel`

I suggest to read the debugger error messages more carefully: "*undeclared identifier*" means that the variable hasn't been declared anywhere (or that the compiler can't find it).

Comment: Thanks lol, did not realize

Comment: No problem, mistakes happen

Answer (score 0):

spelling mistake :)

in while you have used

```
    typSel
```

but real is

```
    typeSel
```

:p :p :)

Answer (score 0):

You have have used two different variables, instead of one.

```
int quantity, typeSel;
```

It creates Integer type variable- typeSel, while you are using:

```
while(typSel != 1 && typSel != 1 && typSel != 1);
```

But you havent initialised typSel.